# BroadcastReceiver for incoming calls is not fired after some time

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an app which is to send text messages to for every incoming call. BroadcastReceiver is registered in service which is foreground. For some reasons the broadcast receiver for incoming calls is not fired. If the user destroys and starts service, the app works for some time. After sometime incoming call receiver is not fired.

Here is the service class:

```
public class SendSmsService extends Service {

private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendSmsService.class);

private static final String SMS_SENT = "com.sms.sendsms.SMS_SENT";
private static final String SMS_DELIVERED = "com.sms.sendsms.SMS_DELIVERED";
private static final int MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 160;
private static final int SMS_PORT = 16001;
private int mLastState = -1;
private static String recipientNumber;
private int smsNumber=1;

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private User user;
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private TelephonyManager telephony;
private PendingIntent keepAlivePendingIntent;
private SharedPreferences prefs;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LOGGER.info("Service is onCreate");
    mNotificationManager
            = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SendSmsService.this);

    LOGGER.info("registering incomingCallReceiver receiver");
    LOGGER.info("registering receiver: SMS_SEND");
    registerReceiver(sendSmsReceiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_SENT));
    registerReceiver(incomingCallReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED));




    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    telephony = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, KeepAliveAlarmReceiver.class);
    keepAlivePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY,
            keepAlivePendingIntent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    LOGGER.info("Service is onStartCommand");
    sharedPref.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.is_service_running), true).apply();
    user = ApplicationLoader.getApplication(SendSmsService.this)
            .getDaoSession()
            .getUserDao()
            .queryBuilder()
            .unique();
    int iconId = R.drawable.icon;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SendSmsService.this)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(iconId)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent nIntent = getPackageManager().
            getLaunchIntentForPackage(ContextConstants.PACKAGE_NAME);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SendSmsService.this, 0, nIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    startForeground(NotificationConstants.LAUNCHER_SERVICE_NOTE_ID,
            notificationBuilder.build());
    return START_STICKY;

}

private BroadcastReceiver sendSmsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LOGGER.info("sendSmsReceiver is received");
        String message;

        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.msg_sent) + " " + recipientNumber;
                SmsLog smsLog = new SmsLog();
                String dateString = (String) DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a", new java.util.Date());
                smsLog.setSentDate(dateString);
                smsLog.setSentNumber(recipientNumber);
                ApplicationLoader.getApplication(SendSmsService.this)
                        .getDaoSession()
                        .getSmsLogDao()
                        .insert(smsLog);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_msg);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.no_service);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_pdu);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.radio_off);
                break;
            default: {
                message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_error_sent_msg);
                break;
            }
        }

        showSmsSendNotification(message);
        LOGGER.info("sendSmsReceiver message = " + message);
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LOGGER.info("Service is onDestroy");
    sharedPref.edit().putBoolean(getString(R.string.is_service_running), false).apply();
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    unregisterReceiver(incomingCallReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(sendSmsReceiver);
    alarmManager.cancel(keepAlivePendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NotificationConstants.SEND_SMS_MSG);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NotificationConstants.LAUNCHER_SERVICE_NOTE_ID);
    LOGGER.info("Unregistered all receiver and stopped successfully.");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private BroadcastReceiver incomingCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LOGGER.info("IncomingCallReceiver is received.");
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
};

private PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        LOGGER.info("phoneListener state : " + state);
        if (state == mLastState) {
            return;
        }

        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            mLastState = state;
            sendSms(incomingNumber, user.getMessageBody(), false);
        }
                /*after finishing call state android returns CALL_STATE_IDLE*/
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            LOGGER.info("incomingCall finished state = " + state);
            mLastState = -1;
        }
    }
};

private void showSmsSendNotification(String message) {
    boolean isEnabledNty = sharedPref.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.is_enable_notifying), true);
    LOGGER.info("Enable notification = " + isEnabledNty);
    if (isEnabledNty) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SendSmsService.this)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
        mNotificationManager.notify(NotificationConstants.SEND_SMS_MSG, notification);
    }
}

private void sendSms(String phoneNumber,String messageText, boolean isBinary) {
    LOGGER.info("Sending sms to phoneNumber = " + phoneNumber);
    if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.isEmpty()) {
        LOGGER.info("Failed: Couldn't sent message to number = " + phoneNumber);
        mLastState = -1;
        return;
    }
    if (ApplicationLoader.getApplication(this)
            .getDaoSession()
            .getBlackListDao()
            .queryBuilder()
            .where(BlackListDao.Properties.Number.eq(phoneNumber)).buildCount().count() != 0) {
        LOGGER.info("Failed: Number in blockList = " + phoneNumber);
        mLastState = -1;
        return;
    }

    if (messageText == null || messageText.isEmpty()) {
        LOGGER.info("Error: Sending msg content empty or null message = " + messageText);
        mLastState = -1;
        return;
    }

    List<SmsLog> smsList = ApplicationLoader.getApplication(this)
            .getDaoSession()
            .getSmsLogDao()
            .queryBuilder()
            .where(SmsLogDao.Properties.SentNumber.eq(phoneNumber))
            .build()
            .list();
    int smsListSize = smsList.size();
    if (smsListSize > 0) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        String period = prefs.getString("send_sms_period", res.getString(R.string.everytime));
        String everytime = res.getString(R.string.everytime);
        String onceADay = res.getString(R.string.once_day);
        String onceAWeek = res.getString(R.string.once_week);
        String onceAMonth = res.getString(R.string.once_month);
        long settingsPeriod = 0;
        if (period.equals(everytime)) {
            settingsPeriod = ContextConstants.EVERYTIME_PERIOD;
        } else if (period.equals(onceADay)) {
            settingsPeriod = ContextConstants.ONE_DAY_PERIOD;
        } else if (period.equals(onceAWeek)) {
            settingsPeriod = ContextConstants.WEEK_DAY_PERIOD;
        } else {
            settingsPeriod = ContextConstants.MONTH_DAY_PERIOD;
        }

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a");
            Date date = format.parse(smsList.get(smsListSize - 1).getSentDate());
            Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
            thatDay.setTime(date);
            if (settingsPeriod != ContextConstants.EVERYTIME_PERIOD &&
                    !DateUtil.isMoreThanSelectedDays(thatDay, settingsPeriod)) {
                LOGGER.info("SEND SMS PERIOD = " + settingsPeriod +  " LAST SENT SMS date = " + date.toString());
                return;

            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("It is the first time to send sms size = " + smsList.size());
    }

    LOGGER.info("Sending probable success ");
    recipientNumber = phoneNumber;
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);


    messageText = messageText+" "+smsNumber;
    smsNumber++;
    ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(messageText);

    int partsCount = parts.size();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<>(partsCount);
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<>(partsCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < partsCount; i++) {
        sentIntents.add(i, piSend);
        deliveryIntents.add(i, piDelivered);
    }

    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
}
}
```

I have spent four days. I am unable to find the bug and going nuts. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to register this receiver in `Manifest` and make it `GLOBAL RECEIVER` so that it can work even if app is not in foreground.

Comment: Service is in foreground and receiver is registered in service. If the reason that you have mentioned is true then how come it is working for hours when application's onDestroy method is called.

Comment: application's onDestroy or service's onDestroy

Comment: application's onDestory

Comment: Then the only reason visible is that `receiver` is not getting registered again, try moving it in onStartCommand()

Comment: I did not get you. Can you explain why this is happening.

Comment: You need to take followup of events happening after onDestroy of service is called once

Comment: So you are saying when service is destroyed by the system at that time broadcast receiver is unregistered. Later service is re-created and onCreate is not called so we need to place registration of receiver in onStartCommand()

Comment: I moved receiver registration code in onStartCommand block. If now I toggle the service then receiver wont get fired.